# Could not start ionic project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I just start using ionic framework and I have install all things which is necessary to run ionic app. 
I have set up simple ionic app using

```
ionic start todo blank
```

When I run this app from root of the project it throws error:

```
Error occured [ReferenceError: IonicProject is not defined]

ReferenceError: Utils is not defined
    at Object.IonicTask.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/serve.js:36:12)
   -----------

Utils is not defined (CLI v1.6.4)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS 
Node Version: v5.1.1
```

Comment: from where exactly and how are you running the app?

Comment: Go to your project root folder and run "ionic serve"

Comment: If you are using mac system then use sudo ionic start todo blank  and if you have windows system try to use nodeJS command prompt

Answer (score 1):

1. You need NodeJS's last stable version installed, after run

   npm install -g npm@latest
2. I recommend you, uninstall global cordova:

   npm uninstall -g cordova

When you finished, run again

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

It's all... create new project and run server.